# Is there a term that refers to the part of the line after the indentation?

Tags: word-choice

The correct term would describe `some text...` in the following example:

```
          some text ...
\ indent /\     ?     /
```

Answer (score 2):

How about simply calling it *indented text*?

Comment: This would work. I'd prefer a term that doesn't use an adjective, though.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* the **line**.  The indenting isn't part of the line of text at all.

Comment: That's great, but then I'd need a term that refers to the whole thing - both the line and the indentation. Could you think of one?

Comment: Not if indenting is a property of the line, rather than an entity in itself.  But regardless, when you invent tasks outside the bounds of English Language, then you will need to develop jargon of your own to do it.  A general name for invisible stuff is 'whitespace'